# python configparser delimiter

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make changes to my file with configparser in Python. I have a configuration file like the one below. I want to use it as #mysql, not as [mysqld] How can I do that ?

```
#mysqld
host = 192.168.1.100
port = 3306
```

Comment: How should read the documentation. It explains really well there. https://docs.python.org/3/library/configparser.html#quick-start

Comment: If I could find it I wouldn't ask here!

Comment: First things first dont be rude cuz I'm only trying to help you, if that wasn't your intention sorry for miss reading the comment. The second thing in the docs second tutorial explains how to manipulate files.

Comment: I m not rude, i never meant that and thanks for your help. I think i should use classic read/write file. I just want to write file as below without square bracket 
`
#bitbucket.org
User = hg
`